# Access was denied during "FlushIpNetTable" call, despite elevated privileges

Tags: c, windows, winapi, arp

the code compiles correctly, but although I run the code with elevated privileges, I still have access denied.

I run the program like this: runas.exe / user: "admin" FlushIpNetTable.exe

OS: Windows 10 Version 10.0.10240

Does anyone have any suggestions why, despite the increased privileges, I cannot clean this table? :) ?

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")


int main() {

    DWORD res, dwIndex;
    dwIndex=2;
    res = FlushIpNetTable(dwIndex);

    if (res == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) {
        printf("Access is denied.\n");
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    } else if (res == ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER) {
        printf("An input parameter is invalid, no action was taken.\n");
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    } else if (res == ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
        printf("The IPv4 transport is not configured on the local computer.\n");
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }else {
        printf("Use FormatMessage to obtain the message string for the returned error.\n");
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `runas` still isn't the same thing as UAC elevation

Comment: damn, you're right, I didn't think about it at all.

Comment: Right-click on the `.exe` and choose `"Run as Administrator"`.  Or open an elevated command prompt window and run the `.exe` from there. Or, add a UAC manifest to the `.exe` that specifies `requestedExecutionLevel` as `requireAdministrator`.

Comment: is there any dedicated interface in windows api to call UAC message?